# Xam.TabView Header is not scrollable in Xamarin forms

Tags: xamarin.forms, tabview

I am using [Xam.Tabview](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xam.TabView/) plugin in my project.

Everything works fine except the header is not scrollable.

**Below is my code:**

```
<control:XFTabControl 
            x:Name="Tabcomponent"
            VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" 
            TabClicked="Tab_TabClicked"
            HeaderHeight="40" FlowDirection="LeftToRight"
            SelectedIndex="{Binding Index}">
            <control:XFTabControl.XFTabPages>

                    **//Page1**
                    <tabview:XFTabPage>
                    <tabview:XFTabPage.Header>
                        <tabview:XFTabHeader>
                        <Label Text="Tab1"/>
                    </tabview:XFTabHeader>
                    </tabview:XFTabPage.Header>
                    <tabview:XFTabPage.Content>
                        <template:Page1></template:Page1>
                    </tabview:XFTabPage.Content>
                </tabview:XFTabPage>
               </control:XFTabControl.XFTabPages>

                  **//Page2**
                    <tabview:XFTabPage>
                    <tabview:XFTabPage.Header>
                        <tabview:XFTabHeader>
                        <Label Text="Tab1"/>
                    </tabview:XFTabHeader>
                    </tabview:XFTabPage.Header>
                    <tabview:XFTabPage.Content>
                        <template:Page2></template:Page2>
                    </tabview:XFTabPage.Content>
                </tabview:XFTabPage>
               </control:XFTabControl.XFTabPages>
          
</control:XFTabControl>
```

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if that package is still maintained or has documentation but the last update is 10 months ago, as an alternative you can try `TabView` from [XamarinCommunityToolkit](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.CommunityToolkit) which is officially maintained by Xamarin.Forms team and the community.

- [Getting Started with the Xamarin Community Toolkit](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/community-toolkit/get-started)
- **TabView Docs** https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/community-toolkit/views/tabview

Another option would be [Sharpnado.Tabs](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Sharpnado.Tabs) package, [Repo](https://github.com/roubachof/Sharpnado.Tabs)